# Python : Fill columns in a Dataframe with the unique present value of the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fill

Let's say that I have this Dataframe where there are two columns not full.

```
data1 = [12,34,465,678,896]
data2 = ['thx','','','','']
data3 = ['','',34,'','']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(data1,data2,data3)),columns = ['Data1','Data2','Data3'])
print(df)

   Data1 Data2 Data3
0     12   thx
1     34
2    465          34
3    678
4    896
```

I want to fill those columns with the unique value present in the columns. So I would like to get something like that :

```
   Data1 Data2 Data3
0     12   thx    34
1     34   thx    34
2    465   thx    34
3    678   thx    34
4    896   thx    34
```

What is the function that I should use to do that ?

Comment: `ffill` and `bfill`? What do you mean by "unique value present?" Can there be more than one value in the column that you want to fill? Also, are your empty cells `np.nan` / `None`, or are they indeed empty strings?

Comment: `df = df.assign(**df[['Data2', 'Data3']].ffill().bfill())`

Comment: `df.replace('', np.nan).ffill().bfill()`

Comment: Sorry, the english is not my mother langauge. What I meant : there are columns that have only one value and I want to fill with this one. I hope it is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas come to mind:

```
# Pre-work: you want your null values to be actual NaN
import numpy as np

df = df.replace('', np.nan)

# Method 1: FFill / BFill methods
ans = df.fillna('ffill').fillna('bfill')

# Method 2: Use a fillna dict
ans = df.fillna({col: df[col].unique()[0] for col in df.columns})
```

Let me know if either work (I'd prefer the first one)